# Java Server Guessing Game - Multiple Client Issue

Tags: java, multithreading

This is an Issue I am having with my guessing game. Essentially what I want to do is have a server and have many clients connect to it. Currently that is done I am able to connect clients to the server to play a game, a number guessing game. The problem is I want each individual client to be able to play the game. Currently the game is being played on the server itself. So although multiple clients can join, the game starts again each time a client joins. When the correct answer is inputed the server gives the client his score. Just to be clear I am running the server class then I am running the client class. I want to be able to play the game on the client class window not the server window. Here is my code can you please advise me on what to do. The guessing game is derived from the java sun knock knock tutorial. Found here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html 
Thanks.

Client Class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class GClient {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Socket kkSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    try {
        kkSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4444);
        out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: taranis.");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: taranis.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String fromServer;
    String fromUser;

    while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);
        if (fromServer.equals("Bye."))
            break;

        fromUser = stdIn.readLine();
    if (fromUser != null) {
            System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
            out.println(fromUser);
    }
    }

    out.close();
    in.close();
    stdIn.close();
    kkSocket.close();
}
}
```

Server Class

```
 import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*;

public class GServer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    boolean listening = true;

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    System.err.println("Started KK server listening on port 4040");
    while (listening)
    new GThread(serverSocket.accept()).start();

    serverSocket.close();
}
}
```

Protocol Class

```
import java.util.*;


public class GProtocol {
int guess = 0, number = new Random().nextInt(100) + 1;
int score = 10;
int guessmade = 0;
boolean gameRunning = true;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


public String processInput(String theInput) {
    String theOutput = null;


    String ID;
    System.out.println("Please Enter your ID...");
    ID = scan.next( );

    System.out.println("Please guess the number between 1 and 100. You have 10 guesses. Your score is however many guesses you have left");

    while (guess != number)
    {

        try {


        if ((guess = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine())) != number) {

          System.out.println(guess < number ? "Higher..."  : "Lower...");
          score = score - 1; // here the score variable has one value taken away form it each time the user misses a guess
          guessmade = +1; // here the guess made variable is given +1 variable
        }
        else {
          System.out.println("Correct!");


        }

        }



      catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter valid numbers! '");

      }   






    }   


    theOutput = ID + "  your score is " + score ; // here the score is returned

    return theOutput;}}
```

Thread class

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GThread extends Thread {
private Socket socket = null;

public GThread(Socket socket) {
super("GMultiServerThread");
this.socket = socket;
}

public void run() {

try {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));

    String inputLine, outputLine;
   GProtocol kkp = new GProtocol();
    outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
    out.println(outputLine);

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
    out.println(outputLine);
    if (outputLine.equals("Bye"))
        break;
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
    socket.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "on the client window" ? ... Ah I see. Of course you'll have to send the messages to the client (via the socket), not to System.out.

Answer (score 1):

In Protocol class, you write Messages to `System.out`. The instance of the `Protocol` class is executed in the environment of the server, thus the output is printed to the server's output. To show the output in the client's console, you'll have to send the messages via the socket to the client and print it there.

Comment: Ah, I totally missed what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: Nevermind. I had problems, too until I saw those "System.out.println"s

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, the preferred thing to do is to [**implement** `Runnable` instead of **extend** `Thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread). That doesn't necessarily fix your problem tho.

Now, the thing that's confusing is what you're actually trying to achieve. You said you want multiple clients to play the game, but right now each client that connects to the server starts a new game. I would assume that's the right way to do it, but you seem to want to have a single game instance and multiple clients simultaneously playing on it. That's very counter-intuitive, however you can achieve it if you simply create a single instance of the `GProtocol` class, pass it to multiple clients and use the `synchronize` keyword to ensure thread safe access to its data.